# What is a family of lines?

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis

And furthermore, how do we define the dimension of the family? My question derives from the stating of the Wolff axiom - *Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a two-dimensional family of lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that no (affine) plane contains more than a one-dimensional family of lines in $\mathcal{L}$.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *affine group* $GL(3, \Bbb R) \ltimes \Bbb R^3$ acts transitively on the space $X$ of lines in $\Bbb R^3$, and so we may view $X$ as a homogeneous space $(GL(3, \Bbb R) \ltimes \Bbb R^3) / H$, where $H$ is the stabilizer of some line in $\Bbb R^3$, which endows $X$ with the structure of a smooth manifold. If a subset $\mathcal{L} \subseteq X$ is, e.g., an embedded submanifold of $X$, we can declare its dimension to be its dimension as a manifold.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what a stabilizer of a line is?

Comment: Sure: Given a group $G$ acting on a set $Y$, the *stabilizer* of an element $y \in Y$ is the set of all group elements $g$ such that the action of $g$ on $Y$ fixes $y$, that is, such that $g \cdot y = y$. Any affine motion of $\Bbb R^3$ can be written as a composition of a linear transformation and a translation, and both of these maps send lines to lines, and hence so do affine motions. Thus, the group of affine motions acts on the space $X$ of lines in $\Bbb R^3$.